# Faithful representation into $\operatorname{GL}(9,3)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Take $T=\big(\left< (123) \right> \times \left< (456) \right> \times \left< (789) \right>\big) \rtimes \left< (147)(258)(369) \right> \leq S_9$.

Does there exist an injective group homomorphism from $T$ into $\operatorname{GL}(9,3)$, such that its image is closed under the operation $(A,B)\mapsto A+B-I$?

Comment: Could you possibly provide some kind of motivation for this question?

Comment: Actually it started with $C_3 \wr C_3$, it can be embedded in $S_9$, as the set $T$ taken above. If I will be able to find this kind of mapping into $GL(9,3)$, then I can say many things about the group ring $F_3(C_3 \wr C_3)$ .

Comment: We can assume that the image lies in a given Sylow $3$-subgroup of ${\rm GL}(9,3)$, so you are asking whether there is a subgroup $S$ of the group of upper unitriangular matrices in ${\rm GL}(9,3)$ with $S \cong C_3 \wr C_3$, such that $\{ g - I : g \in  S \}$ is a group under addition.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, exactly.

Comment: Reversing, it amounts to ask whether there's a 4-dimensional subalgebra of the (non-unital) algebra of strictly upper triangular $9\times 9$ matrices over $\mathbf{F}_3$ on which the law $(a,b)\mapsto a+b+ab$ defines a group law isomorphic to $C_3\wr C_3$.

Comment: Any particular reason to ask about $9\times 9$ matrices?

Comment: @YCor Any $ n \times n$ matrix, $n \geq 9$ will serve.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson That's not true - $C_3 \wr C_3$ embeds into ${\rm GL}(4,3)$. But I have checked by computer that no embedding into ${\rm GL}(n,3)$ for $n=4$ or 5 has the required property. I may be able to check $n=6$ - I am not sure yet - but I will not be able to get up to $n=9$ by naive computation. Still, I am starting to think that no such embedding is possible.

Comment: @Derek : You are right, that was an aberration on my part. Of course, as soon as the minimum polynomial of a unipotent element gets above p, the element has order at least $p^2, $ which is where I was daydreaming.